# understanding '*' "keyword only" argument notation in python3 functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I am having some difficulty behaviour of [keyword only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) feature in python3 when used with [partial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functools.html#functools.partial). Other [info](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter) on keyword only arguments.

Here is my code:

```
def awesome_function(a = 0, b = 0, *, prefix):
    print('a ->', a)
    print('b ->', b)
    print('prefix ->', prefix)
    return prefix + str(a+b)
```

Here is my understanding of partial:

```
>>> two_pow = partial(pow, 2)
>>> two_pow(5)
32
>>>
```

What I understood is in the above example, `partial` makes the second argument to `pow` function as the only argument of `two_pow`.

My question is why does the following work:

```
>>> g = partial(awesome_function, prefix='$')
>>> g(3, 5)
a -> 3
b -> 5
prefix -> $
'$8'
>>>
```

But I get error in this:

```
>>> awesome_function(prefix='$', 3, 5)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
>>>
```

I know that I can call `awesome_function` directly by

```
>>> awesome_function(prefix='$', a = 3, b = 5)
a -> 3
b -> 5
prefix -> $
'$8'
>>>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the semantics of the [function calls in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls), the rules for the arguments to be passed are as follows

```
argument_list   ::=  positional_arguments ["," keyword_arguments]
                       ["," "*" expression] ["," keyword_arguments]
                       ["," "**" expression]
                     | keyword_arguments ["," "*" expression]
                       ["," keyword_arguments] ["," "**"     expression]
                     | "*" expression ["," keyword_arguments] ["," "**" expression]
                     | "**" expression
```

As you see here, the positional arguments should always appear at the beginning of the function calls. They cannot appear anywhere else. When you do

```
awesome_function(prefix='$', 3, 5)
```

it violates the above rule, as you are passing two positional arguments (`3` and `5`) after a keyword argument (`prefix`). That is why you are getting a `SyntaxError`, as Python is not able to parse the function call expression.

---

But, when you are using `partial` it works, because `partial` creates a new function object and it stores all the parameters to be passed to it. When you actually invoke the function object returned by `partial`, it applies all the positional arguments first and then the keyword arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get - `SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg` - is because you tried to send positional arguments (like `3,5`) after a keyword argument, that is not a valid syntax, and hence a syntax error. In the function call -

```
 awesome_function(prefix='$', 3, 5)
                          ^   ^  ^
                          |     These two are the positional argument.
                          ----- This is the keyword argument.
```

It works when using `functools.partial` because `functools.partial` knows to put positional arguments before keyword arguments , hence when you call the partial function - `g()` - with positional arguments , it sends those positional arguments before the keyword argument . Hence, in your case `g(3, 5) ==> awesome_function(3, 5, prefix='$')` .

A simple example to show this -

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def func(a=0,b=1):
...     print(a,b)
...
>>> ptfunc = partial(func,a=10)
>>> ptfunc(20)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: func() got multiple values for argument 'a'
```

In the above case, when we called `ptfunc(20)`, `20` was passed as positional argument first, and then the keyword argument `a=10` was passed, hence it complained that it got multiple values for the argument `a`.

---

And also as given in [the documentation -](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

> `functools.partial` is Roughly equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def partial(func, *args, **keywords):
>     def newfunc(*fargs, **fkeywords):
>         newkeywords = keywords.copy()
>         newkeywords.update(fkeywords)
>         return func(*(args + fargs), **newkeywords)
>     newfunc.func = func
>     newfunc.args = args
>     newfunc.keywords = keywords
>     return newfunc
> ```