# Python implement abstract method with variadic args and get linter to be satisfied

Tags: python, abstract, abstract-methods

I would like to have:

- Abstract method where you have one keyword arg + variable number of other keyword args
- Concretions can specify any number of keyword args

My problem is, when I try this, pylint complains with: `Parameters differ from overridden 'my_func' method`.

Here is an example:

The abstract method

```
@staticmethod
@abstractmethod
def my_func(config: dict, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Example concretion

```
@staticmethod
def my_func(config: dict, special_case: str)
    do_things()
    return
```

Example call of concretion

```
my_func(config=config, special_case=special_case)
```

Is there a way I can construct my abstract method such that I can have:

- The one keyword arg + variable number of keyword args following
- Concretions having the one keyword arg + finite number of keyword args following
- My linter be happy

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show the entire class which emcompasses my_func, also you should have `self` as first argument in `my_func`

Comment: `special_case` is not a keyword argument, it is a *positional argument*. The linter is telling you that `my_func()` in the implementation requires more arguments than the abstract method, and that's a violation of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). If you want to support keyword arguments that are *optional*, then that's different.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh so actually in my implementation it was a `@staticmethod`.  I have added that in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for pointing that out!  How would I get a variable number of optional arguments?  I suppose that's what I want

Comment: @IntrastellarExplorer: either use [keyword-only arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138459/understanding-keyword-only-argument-notation-in-python3-functions) or give your arguments default values.